# How to browse Local host website from Browser

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, localhost

I make hosting for ASP.NET Website on my Local host IIS, and when I browse it by click on Browse from IIS manager it work fine,

But when I browse by write 192.168.1.106:80 in the google chrome browser, it not work
It go to google search.

I want to write 192.168.1.106:80 in browser directly

Comment: Does 192.168.1.106 actually go to that localhost IIS?

Comment: Check in incog mode. Sometimes chrome does not open the pasted/typed link in first go.

Comment: If you don't configure site bindings properly, then no surprise that only `http://localhost` works, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possible solutions:

1. Prefix the **protocol**. paste the full url in the browser:

```sh
http://192.168.1.106:80
```

There can be multiple application on the same server(ip), so the you must tell the browser which protocol to use. In your daily use of browser you don't see `http://` or `https://` prefix because they are so widely used that Chrome hides it to save space in address bar. If you copy the url from Chrome, then paste in any editor, you could see the protocol prefix still there.

2. Check typo
   I'm not very clear if you really typed `192.168.1.106:80`, if you mistyped some of the characters, browser may not recognize the pattern and so go to search. for example, following two will go to search:

- `192.168.1.106：80`
- `192.168.1.10a:80`

Comment: You'd better fix typo, as it should be "protocol". Besides, the browsers are smart enough to append `http://` so in most cases users can skip that.